# Translation files in one module

Tags: angular, translate, angular-translate

I want to load multiple languages translation files in one module. I have come across Multihttploader
Will it be good to use Multihttploader on big application?

Comment: Please, add more information to clarify your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.